# How do I change the default server used by the Live-CD for updates while installing Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, updates, repository, official-repositories

The default server for Taiwan `tw.archive.ubuntu.com` has been down for a while.

So many newbies asked in http://www.ubuntu-tw.org why they could not install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS successfully? Is it hard to change the default download and update server when one install Ubuntu with live CD?

Where can we report this serious and urgent default server failure?

Please see this [forum thread](http://www.ubuntu-tw.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?post_id=234022#forumpost234022) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to overcome this problem is to select a different location when installing, preferably, something geographically close to Taiwan. After the installation, you might need to change the time zone and location, as well as the archive server.

http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ is provided by the "National Taiwan University", so if you wish to report the downtime, please contact that establishment. [Info source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/taiwan-mirror)

Comment: Thank you for your kind attention. It has been years since down often and no improvement. Where can we report it as a bug ?